# How to make Selectable Region Widget from Right to Left Direction

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart-html

I am using a selection area with a selectable region and need to make the direction of selection from right to left (I tried all the RTL solutions for example wrapping with directionality).
but I am not using text, I am using containers here are snippets of my code
here is the demo :
[video](https://7ooda99.github.io/test_app/WhatsApp%20Video%202024-02-25%20at%2016.36.15_0965dbbb.mp4)

```
return SelectionArea(

        child: Stack(
          // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          // textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          // alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          children: [
            ...state.wordsInPage.map((e) {
              double widthScaleFactor = 794.r / width;
              double heightScaleFactor = 1123.r / hight;
              double scaledLeft = e.bbox.x1 * widthScaleFactor;
              double scaledTop = e.bbox.y1 * heightScaleFactor;
              // double scaledRight = e.words.last.bbox.x2 * widthScaleFactor;
              final double lineHeight =
                  convertToLogicalPixels(context, (e.bbox.y2 - e.bbox.y1));

              return Positioned(
                height: 20.h,
                top: scaledTop,
                left: scaledLeft,
                width: (e.bbox.x2.toDouble() - e.bbox.x1.toDouble()) /
                    (width / (794.r)),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: MySelectableAdapter(
                    id: ",${e.id}",
                    child: Container(
                      color: e.isSelected
                          ? Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.5)
                          : Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),

          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Leverage TextDirection and TextAlign:
   Utilize TextDirection.rtl in the Stack widget to set the overall direction for children:

Dart

```
Stack(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  // ... other properties
```

Within each Positioned widget, apply TextAlign.right to the MySelectableAdapter child:

Dart

```
Positioned(
  // ... other properties
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: MySelectableAdapter(
      // ... other properties
      child: Container(
        // ... other properties
        alignment: TextAlign.right, // Set text alignment here
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

2. Adjust scaledLeft Calculation:

Since the selection direction is right-to-left, the starting point (scaledLeft) needs to be calculated based on the rightmost x-coordinate:

Dart

```
double scaledLeft = width - (e.bbox.x2 * widthScaleFactor);
```

This approach adjusts the stacking order and text alignment within each Positioned widget. The `TextDirection.rtl` sets the overall direction, and `TextAlign.right` ensures text and other content align to the right within the container. Finally, adjusting scaledLeft ensures the selection starts from the right based on the rightmost x-coordinate.

Comment: this will not work because i have multiple containers so i can not apply text direction solutions + even if i have only texts will not work because i have multi widgets not one widget